# How Do I Expand A Cell in MUI-Datatables to display additional content?

Tags: mui-datatable

I want a user to be able to click a row in the MUI-Datatable, so they can see additional content. The current `renderExpandableRow` function has the right styling, but I don't want a new row. I want the cell in the first column to show additional data. Is there a way to do this?

Note: I'm also going to need buttons that will expand all/collapse all, so I need a solution flexible enough to do that.

Comment: Can you specify how this should look like? You click on a column and where do you want to data to be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my question.

I made the first column's content a Button using `customBodyRender`. The column with expandable content became the second column. This column has a `customBodyRender` with a Collapse component. I store in my component's state all ids of my data objects and whether or not they are expanded. When the Button is clicked, my component's state is updated, which in turn changes whether or not the Collapse component is open.

I also used `customToolbar` in the table options to generate an expand all/collapse all button, which just sets the state of all rows to expanded/collapsed.